# sas : sorting one column without changing the order of the others

Tags: sorting, sas

I wonder if we can just order one column in sas and keep the same order for the other variables.
usually, we use

> proc sort

with "`by`" but this change the order of all variables according to the variable used in "`by`".

Thank you for help

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  Can you explain the larger problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the sorted column as a new dataset and then merge it back onto the data.

```
proc sort data=have (keep=COLUMN) out=COLUMN ;
  by COLUMN; 
run;
data want ;
  merge have COLUMN;
  * no BY statement ;
run;
```

Comment: Thank You for Help

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a data step by using hash methods - e.g. to reverse the order of the `name` column in `sashelp.class` while keeping the other columns in the same order:

```
data class;
    /*Set up an ordered hash object + iterator to hold the columns we want to sort*/
    if 0 then set sashelp.class(keep = name);
    declare hash h(ordered:'d');
    rc = h.definekey('name','_n_');
    rc = h.definedata('name');
    rc = h.definedone();
    declare hiter hi('h');
    /*Populate the hash object, using _n_ as an extra key to prevent deduplication*/
    do _n_ = 1 by 1 until(eof1);
        set sashelp.class(keep = name) end = eof1;
        rc = h.add();
    end;
    /*Read in the columns in the desired order using the hash iterator*/
    do until(eof2);
        set sashelp.class end = eof2;
        rc = hi.next();
        output;
        drop rc;
    end;
run;
```

This assumes that you have sufficient memory to hold the columns being sorted.

Comment: Thank You for Help

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with PROC SORT. You will need to split the data into sorted and non-sorted datasets, then merge then back together one-to-one without "by" statement using a data step. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001318478.htm

Regards,
Vasilij

Comment: Thank You for Help